# JSF / RichFaces - How to call programatically an ActionEvent from HtmlAjaxSupport (a4j:support)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm doing this

```
htmlAjaxSupport.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression(
                        "#{questionarioMB.visualizarQuestoesFilhos}", null,
                        new Class[0]));
```

The method

```
public void visualizarQuestoesFilhos()
```

is called.

But I want to call

```
 public void visualizarQuestoesFilhos(ActionEvent event)
```

**Because this way, I can get which component is being clicked.**

What do I need to **set** in **htmlAjaxSupport** to work?

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158009/deprecated-richfaces-javax-faces-el-methodbinding-replacement-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Create ActionListener expression in JSF 1.2 or newer:***

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MethodExpression actionListener = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
    .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{bean.actionListener}", null, new Class[] {ActionEvent.class});
uiCommandComponent.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(actionListener));
```

To avoid lot of boilerplate code, you can just wrap it nicely in helper methods (if necessary in an helper/utility class), e.g.:

```
public static MethodExpression createAction(String actionExpression, Class<?> returnType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), actionExpression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}

public static MethodExpressionActionListener createActionListener(String actionListenerExpression) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return new MethodExpressionActionListener(context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), actionListenerExpression, null, new Class[] {ActionEvent.class}));
}
```

---

**Get the snippet from another stackoverthread that Adrian provided:**

[Deprecated richfaces javax.faces.el.MethodBinding replacement use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158009/deprecated-richfaces-javax-faces-el-methodbinding-replacement-use)